Regex expression for Mariadb query
I am trying to do a replace on the following string where the last five digits are different in each row-
Stipends

I understand that I should be able to do this with Regex replace but am struggling to get it written correctly to pull the rows I need to work on...I believe there is a hidden space at the beginning of the second row.
Would appreciate any help - I have to include the first row so that it does not replace another url  in the same field that is similarly named.
I have been trying to just see if I can pull the rows I need with a Select query but pull nothing once I get past the first row of the string...is there a way to escape the whole string up to the equals sign?
I have been trying to just see if I can pull the rows I need with a Select query but pull nothing once I get past the first row of the string.  Any additonal characters just pull zero rows.

I removed the [tag:mysql] tag. MariaDB and MySQL are different products, and a solution for one may not be applicable to the other. It would help if you specify exactly the version of MariaDB you use, because this may also affect the solution. Query SELECT VERSION(); to get this information.

Read carefully: Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question. Especially #5 and #3.

Please provide an example of the data.  And use SELECT HEX(col) ... so we can see any strange bytes.  It might be hex A0 from MS Word -- a special blank.  Also provide SHOW CREATE TABLE so we can see what CHARACTER SET and COLLATION is on the column.
